# how to insert settooltiptext for one vertex in a graph?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jung2

I would like to move the mouse over an vertex which was plotted on a JFrame using JUng class and displaying some additional message for that vertex. But I don't know how to set setToolTipText for a vertex. Is there any way? please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following command to insert setToolTipbox to your graph

```
vv.setToolTipText("<html><center>Breast Neoplasms<p>"
            + "Gene interactions</p> </center></html>");
```